# How to implement rate based throttling per client determined by IP, in Google Cloud Armor?

Tags: security, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-armor

I have created a rule and attached it to a policy that throttles requests based on the rate limit I set:

```
rules=[
        gcp.compute.SecurityPolicyRuleArgs(
            action="throttle",
            match=gcp.compute.SecurityPolicyRuleMatchArgs(
                config=gcp.compute.SecurityPolicyRuleMatchConfigArgs(
                    src_ip_ranges=['*'],
                ),
                versioned_expr="SRC_IPS_V1",
            ),
            priority=110,
            description='Rate based throttling for security policies. Currently, in preview mode.',
            preview=True,
            rate_limit_options=gcp.compute.SecurityPolicyRuleRateLimitOptionsArgs(
                conform_action="allow",
                exceed_action="deny(429)",
                rate_limit_threshold=gcp.compute.SecurityPolicyRuleRateLimitOptionsRateLimitThresholdArgs(
                    count=100,
                    interval_sec=60
                )
            )
        ),
        gcp.compute.SecurityPolicyRuleArgs(
            action="allow",
            description="default rule",
            match=gcp.compute.SecurityPolicyRuleMatchArgs(
                config=gcp.compute.SecurityPolicyRuleMatchConfigArgs(
                    src_ip_ranges=["*"],
                ),
                versioned_expr="SRC_IPS_V1",
            ),
            priority=2147483647,
        ),
    ]
```

In the [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/armor/docs/rate-limiting-overview#identifying_clients_for_rate_limiting), it is mentioned that I can have rate limiting per client determined by IP, however, there are no examples and the only obvious way to achieve this seems to be mentioning IPs manually.

From the [Pulumi documentation](https://www.pulumi.com/registry/packages/gcp/api-docs/compute/securitypolicy/#securitypolicyruleratelimitoptions), it seems that mentioning IP on `enforceOnKey` would have this rule issued based on each IP.

Is there a way to throttle just the IP that reaches the limit?

Answer (score 1):

You have configured **src_ip_ranges=['*']**, which means all the IPs will be following the rules which are attached to the security policy.Instead, you can use a single IP or group of IPs by mentioning CIDR range.

The IP addresses or CIDR Ranges can be used as **"x.x.x.x/y"** where y can be /32 for a single ip or /24 for 254 IPs.

Also,there are some examples related to IP mentioned in the [official document](https://cloud.google.com/armor/docs/configure-security-policies#sample-expressions) which will be useful to you in updating the rules in security policy accordingly.

Alternatively, you can use cookies and apply `"inIpRange(origin.ip. 'x.x.x.x/y') && has(request.headers['cookie']) && request.headers['cookie'].contains('cookie\_name=cookie\_value')"`. Here, the cookie may be a unique reCAPTCHA value . For more information related to [attributes](https://cloud.google.com/armor/docs/rules-language-reference#attributes) and [operations](https://cloud.google.com/armor/docs/rules-language-reference#operations) you can refer to the attached documentations respectively.

Hope the above information is useful to you.

Comment: I am looking to apply rules for all IP, but throttle each IP that defies the limits. How do I do that? Would XFF_IP be the right way?

Comment: I’ll investigate this and get back to you with a more detailed response as soon as possible.

Comment: Hey @kiran-kotturi did you look into this? I asked another question specifically discussing the dangers of XFF_IP and whether GCA can be helpful there - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76754673/how-to-verify-xff-ip-is-from-a-known-proxy-or-cdn-while-enforcing-key-in-google

Comment: You can also use the custom headers feature as per the link mentioned below to pass different values to the header.Note that this does not remove any of the other values being received by the client request.The value that you pass to the header will be the first in the header-field. https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/custom-headers